# Is there any way to split a character stream generated from /dev/urandom to different substreams?

Tags: linux, bash, random, stream, streaming

I need to take a high-speed stream of random numbers generated by a hardware device  and split it to different sub-streams. For the testing purposes I considering /dev/urandom as a data source. Is there any linux tool for it? If not - please help with a bash script to do it.
The sum of sub-stream speeds should add up to initial stream speed ( or to be close ). The sub-streams are later sent to end user by creating a socket between netcat and /dev/tcp with usage of file descriptor 3 (or another).

Comment: kindly clarify two points,  you need a data stream and you want it to be split into sub-streams , e.g. you received a 30000 you want it to be split into 10000, 15000, 5000 ???, also should the split be in some order or it should also be random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly consider using the following code:

```
od -An -t o2  /dev/urandom | awk '{ print $2 }' | awk '{$2= $1/4;$3= $1-$2;print $1" "$2" "$3}'
```

The first column will be the main stream, you can choose to split it into n number of columns or streams here I have attempted to split it into two columns. That is the main stream and two sub streams, *the substreams will add up to the main-stream*.

The sample output from the above code is :

```
032621 8155.25 24465.8
163465 40866.2 122599
023403 5850.75 17552.2
100755 25188.8 75566.2
052763 13190.8 39572.2
015401 3850.25 11550.8
062161 15540.2 46620.8
100415 25103.8 75311.2
142550 35637.5 106912
141450 35362.5 106088
057473 14368.2 43104.8
023430 5857.5 17572.5
007112 1778 5334
036372 9093 27279
```

**P.S. I am not very good with awk, so there can be many improvements possible with awk part of the code.**